# Is it possible to use same authentication on classic asp and asp.net 4.5 on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, single-sign-on

I am trying to apply single sign-on to legacy classic asp applications and asp.net applications. I have created a asp.net login page for all aplications. I can successfully pass the authentication ticket from new login page to the old asp.net application and share the session using sql server. However, I cannot do the same thing for class asp applications. Even though I have logged in to the new asp login page, it still redirects me to the new login page when I go to the classic asp applications. I have already checked that their machine keys are the same. The classic asp applications are some .asp pages and html files without web.config before. I added the web.config file to the folder by myself. I can see the machine key in the IIS manger so I think it is reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

Classic ASP and ASP.Net use a different session state object, therefor you're not logged in into your classic ASP site. 
There is a possibility, it's kind of a hack. I used it once and it works pretty well. Please have a look at this blogpost to see if it fulfills your needs. It uses the ASP session cookies from .Net in asp classic to call a .Net page that returns session (login) data:

http://devproconnections.com/aspnet/share-session-state-between-asp-and-aspnet-apps